# Mostrar rutas hijas en sidenavmenu Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo el siguiente menu(sidenav collapsable a la izquierda):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que quiero que al hacer click en "Datos" se despliegue un submenu(Clientes Articulos etc), es posible?

Este es el codigo de mi componente sidenav.component.html:

```
<section [class.sidenav]="isExpanded">
    <div class="toggle">
      <mat-icon (click)="toggleMenu.emit(null)">
        {{ isExpanded ? "keyboard_backspace" : "dehaze" }}
      </mat-icon>
    </div>
    <mat-list class="nav" *ngFor="let route of routeLinks">
     
      <a
        mat-list-item
        routerLinkActive="active-link"
        class="hover"
        routerLink="{{ route.link }}"
      >
        <mat-icon
          mat-list-icon
          [matTooltip]="!isExpanded ? route.name :'home'"
          matTooltipPosition="right"
        >
          {{ route.icon }}</mat-icon>
        <p matLine *ngIf="isExpanded">{{ route.name }}</p>
        
      </a>
      
    </mat-list>
 
  </section>
```

Asi tengo sidenav.component.ts:

```
export class SidenavComponent {
  showMenuDatos=false;
  @Input()
  isExpanded!: boolean;
  @Output() toggleMenu = new EventEmitter();

  public routeLinks = [
    { link: "Home", name: "Escritorio", icon: "dashboard" },
    { link:" " ,name: "Datos", icon: "storage",  children: [
      {
        name: 'Clientes',
        link: ['Clientes'],
        icon: "dashboard"
      }
    ] },
    { link: "Venta", name: "Ventas", icon: "point_of_sale" }
  ];

}
```

Como veran tengo una ruta hija que desearia mostrar.Algun consejo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno encontre algode codigo y lo adapte y quedo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<section [class.sidenav]="isExpanded">
    <div class="toggle">
      <mat-icon (click)="toggleMenu.emit(null)">
        {{ isExpanded ? "keyboard_backspace" : "dehaze" }}
      </mat-icon>
    </div>
    <mat-list class="nav" *ngFor="let route of routeLinks">
      <span *ngIf="route.children && route.children.length > 0">
        <mat-accordion>
          <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                <!-- Cabeceras del submenu -->
                <div fxLayout="row" > 
                  <mat-icon>{{route.icon}}</mat-icon>
                  <p matLine *ngIf="isExpanded">{{ route.name }}</p>
                </div>
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <span *ngFor="let child of route.children">
              <mat-list-item routerLink="[child.route]">
                <!-- Entradas de cada submenú  -->
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" > 
                  <mat-icon>{{child.icon}}</mat-icon>
                  <p matLine *ngIf="isExpanded">{{ child.name }}</p>
                </div>
              </mat-list-item>
            </span>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="!route.children || route.children.length === 0">
        <mat-list-item routerLink="[routeLink]">
          <!-- Entradas principales -->
          <div fxLayout="row" >
            <mat-icon>{{route.icon}}</mat-icon>
            <p matLine *ngIf="isExpanded">{{ route.name }}</p>
          </div>
        </mat-list-item>
      </span>
     
      
    </mat-list>
 
  </section>
```

El caso es que no me encuentra las rutas y ademas se ve el nombre abajo del icono.

Me falta solucionar eso nomas